# What is the function of elif?

Tags: python

If I wanted to check multiple conditions, can't I just use multiple if statements? For example:

```
a = 10
b = 20
if a == b:
  print('equal')
if a < b:
  print('less')
if a > b:
  print('greater')
```

Comment: According to the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial), only one block of an `if..elif..else` structure will be executed. Your current `if..if..if` construct will evaluate all possibilities and execute any that are true.

Comment: Which is particularly useful when some of your conditional expressions take a while to run or aren't necessarily mutually exclusive (but you still only want one thing to happen).

Comment: Yes, you can. However it is not as efficient... Having said that, sometimes I am not concerned immediately with speed and use a series of `if` statements (just like you showed) while I'm working out which would be a better order for the logic, because you can just cut and paste an `if` statement whereas an `elif` needs a little more effort to move around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using multiple if statements will evaluate every `if` for the condition. As the conditions in your example are mutual exclusive, that might have a similar result. However, if `a` or `b` changes in-between, another condition might become true:

```
a = 5
b = 7
if a < b:
    a = b
if a == b:
    b += 1
```

Both conditions evalute True and will be executed. That might not be intended, so use:

```
a = 5
b = 7
if a < b:
    a = b
elif a == b:
    b += 1
```

will only execute the first condition.

Even with mutual exclusive conditions as your example, as every expression has to be evaluated, that will be slower than the second variant.

Note `elif` (aka `else if`) is identical to:

```
if <cond1>:
    pass
else:
    if <cond2>:
        pass
    else:
        if <cond3>:
            pass
```

As you can see, that will very quickly result in the tests run out of the text and is much less readable than:

```
if <cond1>:
    pass
elif <cond2>:
    pass
...
```

This is also more expressive, as a reader has not to check the conditions to be mutual exclusive. The semantics are clear from the beginning.

---

Finally:

Something like:

```
i = 1
if i is None:
    k = 5
elif not (i <= 0):
    k = i
```

will not work using your example.